# javascript audio object addeventlistener not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I have a react component like:

```
class MusicProgress extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { progress: 1, percentage: 1 }
    }

    get_progress() {
        if(!this.audio) {
            this.audio = new Audio(music_url)
        }
        var progress = this.state.progress
        var self = this
        this.audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            var duration = self.audio.duration
        if(!(progress >= duration)) {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                progress += 1
                var percentage = ((progress / duration) * 100).toFixed()
                self.setState({'progress': progress, 'percentage': percentage})
                }, 1000)
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <p>{this.state.percentage}</p>
                {this.get_progress()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here I am assigning audio object to `this` like `this.audio` if `this.audio` is not available. Then I am creating new object.

I am using `this.audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {` to get the `duration` of the audio so that I can calculate the percentage after every 1 second.

At first it works well and I get the percentage after 1 second but after that it does not gives the percentage. After the `percentage` is updated to state `this.audio` does not enter inside `eventListener`

What is wrong in here ? Need suggestion plz

Comment: `loadedmetadata` event fired only once, when file metadata fetched via network. So that you can't use it every second. You need to modify your code to no depend on event every second.

Comment: Why don't you use the timeupdate event?

Comment: @Andrey can you please help me with answer. I am very new to javascript

Comment: @Kaiido I tried but I didnt get duration . Can you plz help me

Answer (score 0):

This is just pseudo code and probably won't work but there are a number of bad practices here.

Do not call a function which calls setState in the render method. It looks like your logic should be happening once for each new audio url.

To that effect you only need to create the audio instance and listen for the event once on init, and if the musicUrl prop changes. NOT every render..

You are also not cleaning up the previous setTimeouts, event listener or audio instance.

I would structure it more like this:

```
class MusicProgress extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      percentage: 1,
      progress: 1,
    };
  }

  // Because you should not setState from the constructor (initAudio does).
  componentDidMount() {
    initAudio(this.props.musicUrl);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.musicUrl !== this.props.musicUrl) {
      this.destroyAudioInst();
      initAudio(nextProps.musicUrl);
      this.setState({
        percentage: 1,
        progress: 1,
      });
    }
  }

  destroyAudioInst() {
    // this.state.audioInst.destroy(); // If necessary
    this.state.audioInst.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata');
    clearTimeout(this.audioTickId);
    this.audioTickId = null;
  }

  initAudio(musicUrl) {
    const audioInst = new Audio(musicUrl);
    let { progress } = this.state;

    audioInst.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
      const duration = audioInst.duration;
      if (progress < duration) {
        this.audioTickId = setTimeout(() => { 
          progress += 1;
          const percentage = ((progress / duration) * 100).toFixed();
          this.setState({
            audioInst,
            progress: progress,
            percentage: percentage,
          });
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.audioInst) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.percentage}</p>
        {this.state.progress}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do `const audioInst = new Audio(musicUrl);` creates new object every time the state is updated

Comment: It creates a new instance when the class is initialised, and if a new musicUrl is passed to it